# gnu parallel supresses output of ssh and scp when using --line-buffer option

Tags: bash, ssh, stdout, gnu-parallel

I am trying to use gnu parallel to run some ssh and scp commands.

When I do NOT use -u or --line-buffer options, I can see the output for each thread after the thread has finished.

Because my ssh commands take a while I want to see output as it occurs.

When I try to use `-u` tagging does not work.

When I try to use `--line-buffer`, I don't get any of the output, even after threads have finished.

I've written this simple test command which behaves in the same way:

```
parallel -q ssh user@{} 'ls && sleep 4 && ls' ::: host1 host2
```

I have been looking at this very similar question https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101360/scp-does-not-display-output-when-used-with-gnu-parallel but the suggested solution of using the script command did not work for me.  Might be because my system is not linux.  (Am using Solaris).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware that in your example only the first `ls` is run remotely? The `sleep 4 && ls` are run locally. Use `-q` to quote the string or \'

Comment: Are both your local and remote systems solaris? Which versions (uname -a)?

Comment: Hi Ole.  Good pickup, have corrected and added -q.  Local uname -a is 'SunOS myhost 5.10 Generic_150401-11 i86pc i386 i86pc', first remote uname -a is 'Linux host1 2.6.32-504.8.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 19 12:09:25 EST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux' Second remote box is also linux.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run the same command on a bunch of machines, use `--nonall`.
https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html#Running-the-same-commands-on-all-hosts

We need to determine whether it is due to ssh or it is a general problem. So test these:

```
parallel --version
parallel --line-buffer 'echo {}; sleep 4; echo {}' ::: a b c
parallel --tag --line-buffer 'echo {}; sleep 4; echo {}' ::: a b c
parallel -S host1 --line-buffer 'echo {}; sleep 4; echo {}' ::: a b c
parallel -S host2 --line-buffer 'echo {}; sleep 4; echo {}' ::: a b c
parallel -S host1,host2 --line-buffer 'echo {}; sleep 4; echo {}' ::: a b c
parallel -S host1 --tag --line-buffer 'echo {}; sleep 4; echo {}' ::: a b c
parallel -S host2 --tag --line-buffer 'echo {}; sleep 4; echo {}' ::: a b c
parallel -S host1,host2 --tag --line-buffer 'echo {}; sleep 4; echo {}' ::: a b c
```

Have you somehow enabled --compress (this would explain the behaviour)?

Comment: Yes, this looks like an alternate way to run a remote command.  However output (on my setup anyway) is held until threads have finished.  Even when using --line-buffer.  When using -u flag I do see output as it occurs, however the tagging doesn't work (which I really need)

Comment: Hi Ole, thanks for taking the time to try and help me.  I've run all of the commands.  It appears that using parallel -S requires that parallel be installed on the remote hosts?  Am getting lots of 'parallel: command not found' errors.   I should have mentioned that I am not able to guarantee that the remote host have parallel installed.

Comment: The remote installation is only used to detect the number of CPUs. You do not need it remotely installed. Maybe we should take the debugging on the mailingliste? parallel@gnu.org